# C# sql sum the column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

this is my sql code... code works fine and return data but if i try to sum then it throws error.. I am using C#.. I want to sum the left1 and right1 column

```
SELECT Left1, Right1, Left_cf, Right_cf, case when Paid=0 then 'Unpaid' else 'Paid' end as 'Status' FROM BinaryWallet WHERE App_ID = "1000"
```

with sum :

```
SELECT sum(Left1), sum(Right1), Left_cf, Right_cf, case when Paid=0 then 'Unpaid' else 'Paid' end as 'Status' FROM BinaryWallet WHERE App_ID = " 1000 "
```

Comment: Whats the error?
SUM is a aggregate function, so you will have to group the dataset.
Post your table structure and expected reult

Comment: you will have to add `Group By` with Sum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use group by `left_cf,Right_cf,Paid` 
In sql Sum statement works with group by

if you add the bottom of your code

```
Group by left_cf,Right_cf,Paid
```

your code will work.

Comment: Column 'MfrdDnet.dbo.BinaryWallet.VID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
SELECT sum(Left1), sum(Right1), Left_cf, Right_cf,
 case when Paid=0 then 'Unpaid' else 'Paid' end as 'Status' 
FROM BinaryWallet WHERE App_ID = " 1000 "
group by  Left_cf, Right_cf,Paid,Vid
```

Comment: Same error.. it doesnt returns any sum..... if i only put Group by left_cf,Right_cf,Paid without sum.. then also same error occurs

Comment: error : Column 'MfrdDnet.dbo.BinaryWallet.VID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user3133175 i updated my answer you have to include all the non aggregate columns in group by clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  sum(Left1), sum(Right1), Left_cf, Right_cf, 
        case when Paid=0 then 'Unpaid' else 'Paid' end as 'Status' 
FROM    BinaryWallet WHERE App_ID = " 1000"
GROUP BY Left_cf,Right_cf,Paid
```